# Making a thumbnail image a link in Bootstrap un-centers it

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a design in Bootstrap and when I try to make a  normally centered thumbnail clickable, it aligns to the left. I can't figure out where the CSS is coming from that's causing it.

I added the HTML and CSS to a jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/DLYds/

The first box is how it should look, the rest of the thumbnails are all links.

It's probably something really simple but I'm just not seeing it for some reason.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try setting your link as a block element with text-align:center; http://jsfiddle.net/DLYds/1/

Answer (score 3):

Bootstrap is aligning `.thumbnail` images with this code:

```
.thumbnail > img {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Your problem is the parent selector `>`. So just create your own CSS rule where that style affects to every image regardless of its relationship with the `.thumbnail`:

```
.thumbnail img {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

This solution respects Bootstrap's way for centering images and does not affect to your text alignment.